# How to ensure pandas.DataFrame.to_csv is flush immediately

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to force `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` flush the csv that it is writing?

In CSV file writing we can do the following (`f1.flush`)

```
with open("t.csv", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f1:
    writer = csv.writer(f1, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(header)  # header
    writer.writerow(row)
    f1.flush()
```

Comment: can you share an example that shows the issue?

Comment: @william007 hey, did you get solution to this ? i am facing same issue, wherein, i am writing dataframe to a text file. `  with open ("filename.txt", 'ab') as f:  df.to_csv(f,header=False,index=False,sep=",")   `  and in parallel another program reads the file in tail mode. Need to use some flushing method to write immediately in text file, so that tail mode works correctly. Right now tail mode is reading incomplete lines. pls help.

Comment: please check my answer and see if it it answers your question

Answer (score 2):

when passing a file path to `pandas.to_csv()`, the function will open a file, write to it, and close the file.

```
df.to_csv('my_output_file.csv')
# the file will now be fully written and fully flushed
```

thus flushing **definitely** happens as part of the OS handling of closing the file.

there is no need or possibility to further *flush*, the complete contents of the dataframe will be in the file